# String to Date conversion

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I am receiving an error of string to date conversion
here's my script

```
 Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

dim oVal as New Collections
'Time stamp
oVal.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Cookies("TimeStarted").Value.ToString, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Nothing), "ofield_starttime")
oVal.Add(dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "ofield_stoptime")
Savetime(oVal)
```

and under public function saveTime(oVal as Collection)

```
Dim sQuery As New SqlCommand
sQuery.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
sQuery.CommandText = "PSC_Timestamp"

With sQuery.Parameters
    .AddWithValue("@PSCStart", Convert.ToDateTime(oVal("ofield_starttime")))
    .AddWithValue("@PSCStop", CDate(oVal("ofield_stoptime")))

End With
sQuery.Connection = myConnection
If myConnection.State = 1 Then 'check if connection open
    myConnection.Close()
End If
myConnection.Open()
sQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()
myConnection.Close()
```

I am receiving this error

> Conversion from string "13-07-2015 13:09:38" to type 'Date' is not valid.

A helping hand is highly appreciated...thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not clear on what technology you are using?  I don't see how it can be asp.net+vb.net, and vba at the same time?

Comment: @sstan it's a vb.net

Comment: Why do you take a date (dt) and then convert it to string and then _back_ to a date?  You also try to take a date (TimeStarted) and then convert it to date.  This code is doing very odd things.  Can you not just store dates directly in the oVal collection?  When dealing with dates and times, use DateTime variables and don't convert to strings.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - I did but I am having an error of date of out range...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out - to rectify this scenario I have to set the calendar format to a desired settings that has the same format that I am using with my application. This resolved the issue of error in date conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't specify where your error is happening.  If it's the following line:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Cookies("TimeStarted").Value.ToString, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Nothing)
```

... then what I find interesting is that you are passing `Nothing` to the final `IFormatProvider provider` parameter. When you do that, it defaults to the current culture.  Is it possible that your current culture is messing up how the data is being parsed?

To ensure consistent behavior, try passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Cookies("TimeStarted").Value.ToString, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

---

If your error is happening with the following lines:

```
.AddWithValue("@PSCStart", Convert.ToDateTime(oVal("ofield_starttime")))
.AddWithValue("@PSCStop", CDate(oVal("ofield_stoptime")))
```

Then, make sure to change the date conversion logic to use `DateTime.ParseExact` and you should be fine.

Comment: sorry for that it under .AddWithValue("@PSCStop", CDate(oVal("ofield_stoptime")))

Comment: And that is vb.net code, right?  Then change `CDate` to use `DateTime.ParseExact(...)` instead.

Comment: Yes I will try your suggestion.

Comment: is this correct format -> .AddWithValue("@PSCStart", DateTime.ParseExact(oVal("ofield_starttime"), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: error of String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Well, you have to debug and see what the string format is.  In your question, it appears that your string is formatted like this: `13-07-2015 13:09:38`.  But when you debug/print the value of `oVal("ofield_starttime")`, what do you see?

Comment: I can't see what you are seeing.  Can you post the value of `oVal("ofield_starttime")`?  Are you sure that it is on that line that you are getting the error?

Comment: here's additional information -   Dim origDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim timeStamp As String = origDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timeStamp, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) where I got the oVal("ofield_starttime")

Comment: Sorry, but now you are asking me to debug your code without access to your data.  My suggestion to you is to write [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Otherwise, I'm very limited in what I can do for you.

Comment: I got the error the DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Cookies("TimeStarted").Value.ToString, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ->7/13/2015 2:27:06 PM it should be -> 7/13/2015 14:27.06.. the format is wrong any suggestion

Comment: Read [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). It will help you write the correct format string for your date.